# Display and navigate inside a website in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

I would like to display my website in a "full screen" mode. To do it, I add to my website this script: https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js. It allows me to display the page in a "full screen" mode.

I upload my footer in order to display a button that activate the full screen mode.
It's working great.

here is my footer:

```
  <li><a href="#" class="fullscreen">Full screen</a><br /></li>
```

here is my Js:

```
if (screenfull.enabled) {
            // Display the button if the browser is compatible 
    $('.fullscreen').show();
}

$('.fullscreen').toggle(function() {
    screenfull.request();
}, function() {
    screenfull.exit();
});
```

Otherwise, when I'm clicking on a link (redirect the user to another page), the "full screen" mode is cancelled. Does any one know how to fix it?

Is it possible to develop a website in a "full screen" mode and allow the user to navigate without quitting this mode? I'm taking any ressources.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see of this library, you need to put the page you are directing the user to in an iframe and then display that iframe. The library you point to has a sample page that includes a sample of how to load an external page in full screen. The code is as follows:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'external-iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://bbc.com');
iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 'no');
iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
iframe.style.top = '0';
iframe.style.right = '0';
iframe.style.bottom = '0';
iframe.style.left = '0';
iframe.style.width = '100%';
iframe.style.height = '100%';
$('#container').prepend(iframe);
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

I pulled this code right out of the example at http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/.