# Navigation website while in fullscreen state in Chrome leaves fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, fullscreen, history.js

With javascript, I'm going into fullscreen mode with

```
document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

When the url of the page changes (even if the change is done by playing with the history) we exit fullscreen mode in Chrome (not Firefox).

Is there something that can be done so that we don't exit Fullscreen mode in Chrome if we're staying on the same domain?

I see here [Display and navigate inside a website in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065652/display-and-navigate-inside-a-website-in-fullscreen) that it can be done with an iframe but I would really rather avoid iframes.

Comment: if the user launches fullscreen instead of javascript it works just fine. a little bit of js should be able to convert a site to using an iframe seamlessley. With history.pushstate, and postMessage(), iframes are not as bad as as they were a few years back.

Comment: Yes but it's the management of both the iframe and the top level window's url that bothers me. Upon exiting fullscreen mode I'd have to take the iframe's location and set it in the top window's location. And then if they were to click back it would bring them all the way to the start.

Comment: it doesn't have to be like that; you can update the url bar as they navigate the frame from the frame itself top.history.pushState, and you can listen for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate events to handle back. if done right, not even an expert can tell the diff without view-source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it is known Chromium bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171670.